# Amplifier circuit explanation

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

I'm using this circuit to amplify a geophone's signals but I'm having trouble understanding exactly how the  circuit's op-amp stages work. I'd appreciate any explanation. I'd also like to know if and, hopefully, how it can be (better?) re-implemented with an in-amp, say like the [AD623](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD623.pdf).

**EDIT:**

I'm hoping to be able to detect footsteps within a few meters radius eventually after the geophone has been buried. But I'm only after re-design mostly because the AD623 is what I have at the moment and not necessarily because the current circuit has issues. Only standard op-amp I have for now is the LM2904, not quite what is needed for such sensitivity, I think. If re-design isn't feasible, I'm okay with simply understanding how the circuit works.

[image: geo amp]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve ….what makes this a poor solution, and what parameters would you want to be better?

Comment: If you come up with a transfer function for each stage of the op amp, you can probably make some good conclusions as to what's going on. Perhaps the there's some compensation that the second amplifier has that redeems the mistakes that the first amplifier failed to do?

Comment: @JackCreasey I've edited the question

Comment: I used to pickup footsteps 100 yards away in isolated areas with a geophone. You can use 80 dB of gain @ 30 Hz BW Change your design.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist When you say 30Hz BW, you mean from maybe 10 to 40Hz right, since I've read most of the energy content is focused below 100Hz? I've tried using the signal samples kurtosis over a second or 2 to detect footsteps based on research I've found. Was this your process as well?

Comment: loss increases with frequency so more range with lower frequency energy , consider Rayleigh surface waves so 1 ~30 Hz

Comment: But for any source the optimal filter is matched to the spectral shape of the signal. Have you tested it on various soil, concrete? We used to detect 300 miles away < 0.1Hz~10Hz from seismic shock tests and had to stop traffic for 10m

Answer (score 1):

A quick explanation of the schematic you show. You should be able to work out the gain and notch frequency.

[image]

Comment: The problem with this design is the inputs are unbalanced yet going into a balanced INA . Get rid of the unbalanced input and direct couple. With a split supply

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is the 2.2M resistor + 100n cap combo also part of the low-pass or the notch? Does the circuit have any particular obvious flaws? Any ideas about if and how this could be re-done with an in-amp?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I'd appreciate it if you could provide a quick sketch of your solution maybe as another answer.

Comment: The 2.2M Ohm and 100nF are part of the bias network using the VCC/2. They have no significance in the filters.